# Finite Products of three terms in term of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

It is known that $$\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + kx_i) = \sum_{j = 0}^ne_j(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)k^j,$$
where $e_j$ is an elementary symmetric polynomial.

What about this product $$\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 - a_i + kx_i) ?$$
Can we expand it in terms of some well-known polynomials (maybe more than one type of polynomials)?

Comment: The later product is a polynomial with zeros in $x_{i0} = (a_i - 1)/k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given  that  $a_i\ne  1, \  1\leq  i\leq   n$  we can bring  it  into a shape similar  to  the original  one.

> We have
>   \begin{align*}
> \prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-a_i+kx_i\right)&=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-a_i\right)\,\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+k\,\frac{x_i}{1-a_i}\right)\\
> &=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-a_i\right)\,\sum_{j=1}^n e_j\left(\frac{x_1}{1-a_1},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{1-a_n}\right)k^j
> \end{align*}